# Is the Astrometa DVB-T2 usb stick working on Ubuntu?

Tags: tv, tv-tuner, ubuntu-tv

I tryed to run DVB-T2 channels with Astrometa DVB-t2 on Ubuntu.

I installed Linux firmware nonfree and media build.
After this I installed w_scan.
If I scan channels with `w_scan` I make `channels.xpsf` file for VLC, but VLC is not playing channels form channel list.

[image: channel list]

VLC sees channels in the channel list but doesn't run any channels.

[image: vlc player error]

Is it possible to make this device to work properly in Ubuntu ?

This is: dmesg | grep -i dvb

```
$ dmesg | grep -i dvb [ 5699.368610] usb 1-1.3: Product: dvbt2
[ 5699.368613] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: astrometadvbt2
[ 5699.592569] usb 1-1.3: dvb_usb_v2: found a 'Astrometa DVB-T2' in warm state
[ 5699.673012] usb 1-1.3: dvb_usb_v2: will pass the complete MPEG2 transport stream to the software demuxer
[ 5699.673035] DVB: registering new adapter (Astrometa DVB-T2)
[ 5699.848970] usb 1-1.3: DVB: registering adapter 0 frontend 0 (Realtek RTL2832 (DVB-T))...
[ 5699.849151] usb 1-1.3: DVB: registering adapter 0 frontend 1 (Panasonic MN88473)...
[ 5699.971702] input: Astrometa DVB-T2 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/rc/rc0/input14
[ 5699.972829] rc0: Astrometa DVB-T2 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/rc/rc0
[ 5699.981172] usb 1-1.3: dvb_usb_v2: schedule remote query interval to 200 msecs
[ 5699.990461] usb 1-1.3: dvb_usb_v2: 'Astrometa DVB-T2' successfully initialized and connected
[ 5699.990558] usbcore: registered new interface driver dvb_usb_rtl28xxu
[ 5700.009679] input: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (dvb_usb_rtl28xxu) as /devices/virtual/input/input15
[ 5700.025429] rc rc0: lirc_dev: driver ir-lirc-codec (dvb_usb_rtl28xxu) registered at minor = 0
[ 6427.072346] mn88473 8-0018: downloading firmware from file 'dvb-demod-mn88473-01.fw'
```